# Name or ID as url for restful api

Tags: rest, restful-url, nested-routes

I currently build a restful api with a `users` route. Is it more idioatic to use the username or his id as parameter if the username is unique?

Either

```
example.com/api/users/johndoe
```

or

```
example.com/api/users/123456
```

Furthermore I planed routes for a `project` resource. Would it be an inconsistent design, if I require the project-id here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually a username can be remembered more easily but I would recommend you to use the ID as in a username there may be spaces or other characters (for example german umlaute) which are difficult to get into good format for an url. It may also be, that a user changes his name. Then all the links would be invalid in opposite to the ID.

Comment: If you want, you can also create a route to a search, such as `example.com/api/users/search?name=johndoe`.

Comment: @pbuch This is a good reason to stick with a static user id. Mostly developer want be in the situation, where they need to call an api manually. So this should not be a big problem.

Comment: I was having the same problem.  The combination of pBuch's answer (use the ID) and ScottOffen's suggestion to add a search for the name seem to work well.  I've tried it out and it seems quite intuitive as far as the URL's go.